# Adding decimal years to a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, decimal, timespan

When I encountered this I thought it would be a trivial challenge involved TimeSpans and basic DateTime arithmetic. Unless I have missed some really obvious I was wrong...

How would you add `13.245` years to `3/22/2023 5:25:00 AM`?

The closest I get is this snippet:

```
long ticks = (long)((365.0M - 4) * (decimal)TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * 13.245M); 
            
DateTime futureDate= new DateTime(2023, 3, 22, 5, 25, 0).AddTicks(ticks);
Console.WriteLine(futureDate.ToString());
```

Which gives me an output of `4/23/2036 4:05:48 PM` that I am not entirely confident in. Also, notice the way I have had to manually handle leaps years with:

```
365.0M - 4
```

Comment: Your manual handling of leap years looks very wrong to me... you're basically treating each year as being 361 days long... but fundamentally, it's not clear what's meant by "add 13.245 years". That's a matter of specification more than code. If you can define *precisely* what you mean, coding it may well be okay.

Comment: `(365.0M - 4)` will give you `361.0`, so you're multiplying the number of years by 361. It's not clear how subtracting 4 from anything "handles leap years"

Comment: I would suggest you start with a simpler question though: what does adding *1* year mean? Test cases to consider: adding 1 year to 2014-06-01T00:00:00; adding 1 year to 2015-03-01T00:00:00; adding 1 year to 2016-02-29T00:00:00. (Just for starters...)

Comment: Since the length of a year is not constant, you need to define what `.245` years means. And what to do if you cross from a year of one length (in days) to the length of another.

Comment: @DStanley that the interesting part of this, because of leap years and different month lengths13.245 is relative to the start datetime so it isn't an absolute timespan

Comment: Which is our point - there's no universal definition of a decimal fraction of a year in terms of date values - you can define is as a percentage of that year (although what if you cross years?) of as a fraction of 365.2425 days, or some thing else. Once you define _that_ in your context you can get a more accurate answer.

Comment: Even more: years' durations are different, in case of *tropical year* (which is the interval between two vernal equinoxes) the difference can be more than `2` minutes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year

Answer (score 1):

I see this:

> How would you add 13.245 years to 3/22/2023 5:25:00 AM?
> ...gives me an output of 4/23/2036 4:05:48 PM that I am not entirely confident in.

That's clearly not accurate. With a starting date in March and fractional year portion of `0.25`, you should expect to end up in **June**, not April.

So let's try this instead:

```
private static DateTime AddYears(DateTime startDate, double years)
{
    startDate = startDate.AddYears((int)years);
    double remainder = years - (int)years;
    double yearSeconds = (new DateTime(startDate.Year + 1, 1, 1) - new DateTime(startDate.Year, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

    return startDate.AddSeconds(yearSeconds * remainder);
}
```

Using the built-in date math functions helps a lot, and going down to the second has the advantage of accepting a double for the final addition, and allowing greater precision. Now we get a result date of `06/21/2036 5:25:00 PM`. This sounds more like it. We're not exactly 3 months later in the year (that would be `6/22/2036 5:25:00 AM`, so we "lost" 12 hours), but not all months are the same, so this looks reasonably accurate.

However, there's still potential for error because the remainder could put us into a new year which has a different length: possible change in the leap year or other things like the odd leap second. For example, say the starting date is `2023-12-31 23:23:59`, and the addition is `0.99`. The code above assumes the year length based on that initial 365 day year (0 whole years to add), but nearly all of the final fractional addition takes place the next year, which has 366 days. *You'll end up [nearly a whole day short](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iu8awf) of where you expect.*

To get more accurate, we want to add the fractional part only up to the end of the year, and then recalculate whatever is left based on the new year.

```
private static DateTime AddYears(this DateTime startDate, double years)
{
    startDate= startDate.AddYears((int)years);
    double remainder = years - (int)years;
    double yearSeconds = (new DateTime(startDate.Year + 1, 1, 1) - new DateTime(startDate.Year, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;

    var result = startDate.AddSeconds(yearSeconds * remainder);
    if (result.Year == startDate.Year) return result;

    // we crossed into a near year, so need to recalculate fractional portion from within the ending year
    result = new DateTime(result.Year, 1, 1);

    // how much of the partial year did we already use?
    double usedFraction = (result - startDate).TotalSeconds;
    usedFraction = (usedFraction/yearSeconds);

    // how much of the partial year is still to add in the new year?
    remainder = remainder - usedFraction;

    //seconds in target year:
     yearSeconds = (new DateTime(result.Year + 1, 1, 1) - result).TotalSeconds;
   
    return result.AddSeconds(yearSeconds * remainder);     
}
```

Knowing Jon Skeet was looking at this question, I wouldn't be surprised if [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) makes this easier. I'm sure there are other potentials for error, as well (at least fractional seconds around the end/start of the year boundary), but I feel like this would put you close enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would first add the whole years (13), than check how much ticks the year have and add the decimals depending on the ticks.
Something like this:

```cs
private static DateTime AddYears(DateTime date, double years)
{
    date = date.AddYears((int)years);
    double remainingYearsToAdd = years - (int)years;

    long ticksInThisYear = new DateTime(date.Year + 1, 1, 1).Ticks - new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1).Ticks;
    long elapsedTicksThisYear = date.Ticks - new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1).Ticks;
    double elapsedPercentageThisYear = 1d / ticksInThisYear * elapsedTicksThisYear;
    if (elapsedPercentageThisYear + remainingYearsToAdd <= 1)
    {
        return date.AddTicks((long)(remainingYearsToAdd * ticksInThisYear));
    }
    else
    {
        remainingYearsToAdd -= elapsedTicksThisYear / (double)ticksInThisYear;
        date = new DateTime(date.Year + 1, 1, 1);
        long ticksInNextYear = new DateTime(date.Year + 1, 1, 1).Ticks - new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1).Ticks;
        return date.AddTicks((long)(remainingYearsToAdd * ticksInNextYear));
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to assume that all months are the same length. For example, suppose we were to have an input of 0.08333333333 years to add, that would add 31 days to a date in January, but 28 or 29 dates to a date in February, which feels unusual to say the least. There's at least nothing in the question to suggest that's how it's been specified.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're totally right. I've updated my answer accordingly and now calculate the ticks. Thank you for your hint. This should be the most accurate way of doing this. Still we don't know the definition of the decimal representation of a year.

Answer (score -1):

Your approach is almost correct, but there are a few issues to consider:

Leap years: As you mentioned, you need to account for leap years since they have an extra day. One way to do this is to calculate the number of days between the two dates and then add the fraction of a day corresponding to the number of leap years in that period.

Precision: The value of "13.245" years is not exact since a year is not exactly 365 days. It's closer to 365.2425 days. This may not matter for small time intervals, but for longer periods it can make a significant difference.

Time zone: The code you provided assumes that the input date is in the local time zone, which may not be what you intended. If you want to work with UTC dates, you should use the DateTimeOffset structure instead of DateTime.

Here's a modified version of your code that takes these issues into account:

```
decimal yearsToAdd = 13.245M;
DateTime inputDate = new DateTime(2023, 3, 22, 5, 25, 0);
int inputYear = inputDate.Year;

// Calculate the number of leap years between the input year and the future year
int futureYear = inputYear + (int)yearsToAdd;
int numLeapYears = Enumerable.Range(inputYear, futureYear - inputYear)
    .Count(y => DateTime.IsLeapYear(y));

// Calculate the number of days to add, including leap years
TimeSpan daysToAdd = TimeSpan.FromDays(yearsToAdd * 365.2425M + numLeapYears);

// Add the days to the input date
DateTime futureDate = inputDate.Add(daysToAdd);

Console.WriteLine(futureDate.ToString());
```

This code calculates the number of leap years between the input year and the future year using LINQ's Enumerable.Range method. It then calculates the total number of days to add, including the fraction of a day corresponding to the partial year and the leap years. Finally, it adds the resulting TimeSpan to the input date to obtain the future date.